# wpf logicaly group controls

Tags: c#, wpf, foreach

I have 32 Checkboxes on my XAML. I want to check which of these are selected by the user.

Is there a way to group these controls, and loop over them, so I can avoid a 32 piece if else decision. So instead of this:

```
  private List<int> GetSelectedPositions() 
    {
        List<int> SelectedPositions = new List<int>();


        if (CheckBoxPos1.IsChecked == true)
        {
            SelectedPositions.Add(1);
        }
        else if (CheckBoxPos2.IsChecked == true)
        {
            SelectedPositions.Add(2);
        }

        //(...)

        else if (CheckBoxPos32.IsChecked == true)
        {
            SelectedPositions.Add(2);
        }

        return SelectedPositions;

    }
```

Something like this:

```
  private List<int> GetSelectedPositions() 
  {
        List<int> SelectedPositions = new List<int>();
        foreach (var item in collection)
        {
            if (item.IsChecked) { SelectedPositions.Add(item.position) }

        }
        return SelectedPositions;
    }
```

Comment: Create a list of bools in your view model. Bind that list to an item control and use a checkbox as the item template.

Comment: @poke why are you not adding that as an answer? like the watermark text in the comment field says *Avoid answering questions in comments.*

Comment: @Default Because I did not have enough time for writing more than that. And that alone isn’t an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your checkboxes are in a Grid or any control that can have multiple children you can do something like this:

```
        bool? isChecked = false;
        foreach (var child in gdMain.Children.Cast<UIElement>())
        {
            if (child is CheckBox)
            {
                isChecked = (child as CheckBox).IsChecked;
            }
        }
```

gdMain is a name of a grid

You can even go fancy and use Linq to get all of the checkboxes that are checked and put them in an ienumerable or a list:

```
var checkBoxes = gdMain.Children.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(x => x.IsChecked == true);
var checkBoxes = gdMain.Children.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(x => x.IsChecked == true).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to check *all* the 32 checkboxes, without filtering, you can get all the checkbox controls and check their `Checked` property. Here is a sample code:

```
var ctrls = this.Controls.OfType<System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox>().ToList();
foreach (var ctrl in ctrls)
   if (((CheckBox)ctrl).Checked)
   { 
       SelectedPositions.Add(item.position)
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

ViewModel:

```
/// <summary>
            /// The <see cref="IsChecked" /> property's name.
            /// </summary>
            public const string IsCheckedPropertyName = "IsChecked";

            private bool _IsChecked = false;

            /// <summary>
            /// Sets and gets the IsChecked property.
            /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
            /// </summary>
            public bool IsChecked
            {
                get
                {
                    return _IsChecked;
                }

                set
                {
                    if (_IsChecked == value)
                    {
                        return;
                    }

                    RaisePropertyChanging(IsCheckedPropertyName);
                    _IsChecked = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(IsCheckedPropertyName);
                }
            }
```

Xaml:

```
  <CheckBox  Margin="10"  IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

You can use MVVM Architecture like this with binding your property name with it So code will easily understable and writable.